# mybatis works in @Test but not int the main code

Tags: java, spring, spring-mybatis

I'm using mybatis-spring in a concept test. All is working with my database when I'm running the test but when use the code in a service I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

My DaoTest:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="/spring-config.xml")
public class DaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private IOrdenMgmtDao ordenDao;

    @Test
    public void testDAO(){
        Assert.assertNotNull(ordenDao);
        Integer countForOrden = ordenDao.getCountByState("NEW");
        Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(3), countForOrden);
        List<OrdenDetailStateResult> ordenDetail = ordenDao.getOrderDetail("NEW");
        Assert.assertNotNull(ordenDetail);

        for (OrdenDetailStateResult ordenDetailStateResult : ordenDetail) {
            System.out.println(ordenDetailStateResult.getOrden_id() + " "
                + ordenDetailStateResult.getComprador_email() + " "
                + ordenDetailStateResult.getStatus());
        }
    }
}
```

The test results are ok:

```
...
13:48:29.027 [main] DEBUG o.a.p.b.i.I.getOrderDetail - <==      Total: 3
5835561 quintero@mail.co NEW
5835562 quintero@mail.co NEW
5835761 andrmas@mail.com NEW
...
```

But when I try to use with a rest service: `http://localhost:8080/batisrest/webapi/orders/NEW`, I get:

`java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.agonzalez.batisrest.service.OrderService.getCountByState(OrderService.java:22)`

I access it through the OrderResource class:

```
@Path("/orders")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class OrderResource {

    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    @GET
    @Path("/{orderStatus}")
    public String getOrdersByStatus(@PathParam("orderStatus") String  orderStatus){
        return Integer.toString(orderService.getCountByState(orderStatus));
    }
}
```

My OrderService class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations="/spring-config.xml")
public class OrderService {

    @Autowired
    private IOrdenMgmtDao ordenDao;

    public int getCountByState(String orderStatus){
        Integer countForOrden = ordenDao.getCountByState(orderStatus);
        return countForOrden;
    }

}
```

The IOrdenMgmtDao that is connected with mybatis:

```
public interface IOrdenMgmtDao {

    public Integer getCountByState(
            @Param("ordenStatus") final String ordenStatus);

}
```

I think the main problem is from the configuration but I can't see it. There are my spring-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mybatis-spring="http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring
    http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring-1.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

    <mybatis-spring:scan base-package="org.agonzalez.batisrest.**" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
        //[Database configuration working]
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactoryBean" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml"></property>        
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:spring-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.agonzalez</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.agonzalez</groupId>
    <artifactId>batisrest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>batisrest</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <build>
        <finalName>batisrest</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.21</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

As I said, the test are working connected with my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the compatibility of the dependencies than couldn't be seen from eclipse. Here is final pom.xml I'm using:

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.agonzalez</groupId>
    <artifactId>batisrest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>batisrest</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <build>
        <finalName>batisrest</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.21</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.1.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!--Servlet 3+ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    <!--SPRING -->
    <!--Spring Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Spring Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Spring JDBC -->
        <dependency>    
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Spring My Batis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!--Spring Jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!--Web Services With Jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--My BatisC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: That is a very old version of HikariCP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to autowire your orderService in your OrderResource class.

Change

```
OrderService orderService = new OrderService();
```

TO:

```
@Autowired
private OrderService orderService;
```

Avoid creating object with `new` operator in Spring applications. Since you are creating your oderService with new operator it won't have the dependency it needed for the dao object.

Comment: I update my code with `@Autowired` but I still have the `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Can you debug and see which object is null?

Comment: This is the null object: private OrderService orderService;

Comment: Try adding a `<context:component-scan>` in your spring xml file and see if that makes a difference. `<context:component-scan base-package="your.package.declaration" />`

Comment: I added `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd` to `xsi:schemaLocation` and `<context:component-scan base-package="org.agonzalez.batisrest" />` but still have the same `java.lang.NullpointerException`.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace in your console? Your basic bean injection is not working. Spring can't seem to autowire your bean. I am wondering if we can talk in chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92407/discussion-between-yogidilip-and-andrefontaine).

Comment: The chat is blocked by the company proxy. I think you are right @yogidilip spring can't seem to autowire the bean. Is somehow to send a DM here?

Comment: I am not sure there is one.

Comment: Try putting @Component annotation at the top of each of your class and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: I added `@Component` to my classes but does not work. Maybe I'm forgeting any dependency?

Comment: This is the only way that works for me. However I know that is not the best way. XmlBeanFactory is deprecated.   

`BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("spring-config.xml"));
 OrderService orderService = (OrderService) factory.getBean("orderService");` I also have to add `@Service("orderService")`

Comment: Add <context:annotation-config /> at the top of your bean declaration. That should solve your issue.